# Folder permission on server while uploading?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-3.5, file-permissions

I want to upload files in my Asp.net application on server but I have to grant it R/W access so that I or anyone can upload files in it. Is there any way that I write some code or configuration lines in Web.config which solve this permission problem?

Comment: There is no way around this - the windows user under which your application is running must have read/write access to the folder where you are going to save files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the permissions on the folder for the account under which your application is running.  This is an operating system level, and hence nothing can be done about it in Web.config.  Be careful to only set the permissions on the one folder though, as your effectively opening it up to the internet through your application.